# GROUP BY HAVING COUNT SQL NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to run a query to pull the b.OPRID from PSOPRDEFN where the EMPLID has at least one row in ps_DEDUCTION_BAL meeting the following criteria in the query below.  However, when I run this it returns no data which I don't think is right.  Is there an issue with my query?

```
SELECT b.OPRID
  FROM ps_DEDUCTION_BAL a, PSOPRDEFN b
 WHERE     a.PLAN_TYPE = '4A'
       AND a.DED_YTD > 0
       AND a.BALANCE_YEAR >= '2015'
       AND a.BALANCE_PERIOD >= '6'
       AND a.EMPLID = b.emplid
       AND b.OPRID LIKE 'ZZ%'
       GROUP BY b.OPRID
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: your query asks for at least two rows, not one

Answer (score 2):

Use `exists`:

```
SELECT b.OPRID
FROM pPSOPRDEFN b
WHERE OPRID LIKE 'ZZ%' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM s_DEDUCTION_BAL a
              WHERE a.PLAN_TYPE = '4A' AND a.DED_YTD > 0 AND
                    a.BALANCE_YEAR >= '2015' AND a.BALANCE_PERIOD >= '6' AND
                    a.EMPLID = b.emplid
             );
```

This should have better performance than your version, which requires aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

At least one row should be:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
```

not

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to GROUP BY, DISTINCT will do the trick

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.OPRID
FROM ps_DEDUCTION_BAL a, PSOPRDEFN b
 WHERE     a.PLAN_TYPE = '4A'
       AND a.DED_YTD > 0
       AND a.BALANCE_YEAR >= '2015'
       AND a.BALANCE_PERIOD >= '6'
       AND a.EMPLID = b.emplid
       AND b.OPRID LIKE 'ZZ%'
```

Answer (score 0):

The join between the tables, that you perform here:

```
a.EMPLID = b.emplid
```

actually drops all rows in `PSOPRDEFN` that have no matching rows in `ps_DEDUCTION_BAL`, so simple `DISTINCT` will do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.OPRID
  FROM ps_DEDUCTION_BAL a, PSOPRDEFN b
 WHERE     a.PLAN_TYPE = '4A'
   AND a.DED_YTD > 0
   AND a.BALANCE_YEAR >= '2015'
   AND a.BALANCE_PERIOD >= '6'
   AND a.EMPLID = b.emplid
   AND b.OPRID LIKE 'ZZ%'
```